# C code to find 3 digit numbers in an interval which satisfies the criteria sum of first and last=middle

Tags: c

I have to find out how many 3 digit numbers are there in an interval [a,b] which satisfies criteria sum of first and last digit = middle digit . For eg: 121,143 etc.
Below is the code of loop for the same

```
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        first=a;
        last=a%10;
        temp=a/10;
        middle=temp%10;
        while(first>10)
        {
            first=first/10;
        }

        sum=first+last;
        if(sum == middle)
        {
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
```

But I am not getting the correct answer. Eg: in interval [100,130] , output should be 2 whereas I am getting 0 itself.

Please help out. Thanks .

Comment: `first=a;
        last=a%10;
        temp=a/10;` : Use `i` instead of `a`.

Comment: Why not `first = temp / 10;` (after `middle = temp % 10;`)?  What is the value in `first` in your code?  What is in middle?  What is in last?  Why didn't you print this information to show you what's going wrong?  You have a choice.  Use a debugger to step through the code, or add print statements to show what's going on.  I tend to prefer print statements, but there are arguments either way.  You should, however, use one or the other to find out what's going on.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : thanks, that was so stupid of me . My bad

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks buddy. Debugging code was already in place . I just wanted to make things short here. Thanks for the help, worked out

Comment: If the debugging code had been in place, you wouldn't have needed to ask this question.  Sorry, but I simply don't believe you.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step and query its state to understand more its behaviour.

Comment: Can't resist: `if (0==(i%11)){count++;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
    first=i;
    last=i%10;
    temp=i/10;
    middle=temp%10;
    while(first>10)
    {
        first=first/10;
    }

    sum=first+last;
    if(sum == middle)
    {
        count=count+1;
    }
}
printf("%d",count);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace a with i in your loop.

```
 for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
{
     first=i;
     last=i%10;
     temp=i/10;
     middle=temp%10;
    while(first>10)
    {
        first=first/10;
    }

    sum=first+last;
    if(sum == middle)
    {
        cnt=cnt+1;
    }
}
printf("%d",cnt);
```

This will give you correct result :)